# How can I use vnode or binding directive to call a component method in VUE 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-directives

I created a directive, and I need to make that directive call a function that exists inside the component that has the directive.

```
// Component with directive, this component has the method 'setDisabled()'
<v-button v-can:edit.disable="[something]" @click="add" />


// Directive created
const can = {
    mounted: async (el, binding, vnode) => {
        let hasAccess = validateAccess()
        if (!hasAccess) {
            // should call v-button setDisabled() in here
        }
    },
}
```

In VUE 2 that was achievable by using vnode.context, but in VUE 3 it seems like I can only access methods from the parent component with binding.instance.

So, is there a way to use el, binding or vnode, after the component is mounte to call a method? So far just saw the props in vnode, no methods or reactive data.

Comment: "methods from the parent component" - not true. binding.instance is current instance, as it could be expected. If you have problem with this, consider addressing it. It's very specific to the component, but you ask in general. Is it Vuetify? Then you could verify first if there's really such method

Comment: 'v-button' is a custom component. And yeah, 'binding.instance' is returning the instance of the component that has v-button in it's template. I'm trying to access the methods from the 'v-button' that has the directive on

Comment: The directive is designed for DOM manipulation purposes. If you want to call component methods, why not pass a prop and call the method inside the component based on that prop? Another way you can reference the component is by using `ref` in its parent. No need to use a directive at all when you don't want to manipulate the DOM

Comment: @Duannx The idea is to have a directive that can call a method inside the component when that method exists. As the directive is triggered on the mounted hook, all the methods are ready to be used. Using a prop would force a re-render of the component, which seems unnecessary. I tried to use the REF, but I would need to set the ref and pass it in the directive to achieve that. Having a directive accessing the component methods should not need all that.

Comment: If your component state is dependent on a prop so the re-render is necessary. It is the way Vue deals with reactive data. The main point that I want to say is calling the component method in the directive is an unexpected way. It looks clean but might cause some side effects and be hard to maintain. I recommend not to use it

Comment: I did figure out a way to do this, works perfectly. I just added the bounty to see if there was a proper way, I kinda had to dig in the nodes to get there. If when the bounty expires we don't have a cleaner way, I'll post how I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Hacked solution for Vue3

### Constraints

1. The Vue Doc clarifies

> [Official Docs: Script Setup](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose)
> Components using `<script setup>` are closed by default - i.e. the public instance of the component, which is retrieved via template refs or $parent chains, will not expose any of the bindings declared inside .
>
> [Official Docs: Custom Directives](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/custom-directives.html#usage-on-components)
> In general, it is not recommended to use custom directives on components.

2. The `binding.instance` argument passed to the directive hook represents

   - The parent component having an element/component that uses the v-directive
   - Not the component that defines the v-directive.
3. The `vnode` argument passed to the directive hook represents

   - The element that uses v-directive for `Native DOM Element`
   - The root element of component that uses v-directive for `Custom component with single root`
   - The first root element of component that uses v-directive for `Custom component with multiple roots`

### However

1. You can access the custom **component instance** using vnode
2. And you can **access underlying method** of the custom component from vnode using

   - Expose `vnode.el.__vueParentComponent.exposed`
   - Provide `vnode.el.__vueParentComponent.provides`

### Solution:

1. Expose the component method using defineExpose

```
const setDisabled = () => { /* Your precious method */};
defineExpose({
  setDisabled
});
```

2. Access the exposed method using vnode

```
const vCan = {
  mounted: async (el, binding, vnode)=> {
    vnode.el.__vueParentComponent.exposed.setDisabled()
  },
};
```

3. Also ensure the directive definition object is defined using camelCase and has v prefix like `vCan`

Comment: Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-g1zgor?file=src/App.vue